# Replace words that partially match over a list

Tags: r

I have a list of names belonging the dataset `mammalsleep`, and I want to replace those names that have additional characters on the name.

For example:

```
pr_replace <- paste(c('log(brain)','I(body^2)'), collapse="|")
extract_replace <- paste(c('brain','body'), collapse="|")
```

We replace `extract_replace` for `pr_replace`.

I have tried two ways of doing this:

```
  lapply(per, function(dat)
    sapply(dat, function(x)
      str_replace(x, extract_replace, pr_replace)) %>% data.frame())
```

Would instead replace the values when found with

```
                X9
1             exposure               danger log(brain)|I(body^2)
2               danger log(brain)|I(body^2) log(brain)|I(body^2)
3 log(brain)|I(body^2) log(brain)|I(body^2)             nondream
4 log(brain)|I(body^2)             nondream                dream
5             nondream                dream                sleep
6                dream                sleep            gestation
7                sleep            gestation            predation
8            gestation            predation             exposure
9            predation             exposure               danger
```

I have also tried:

```
pr_r<-c('log(brain)','I(body^2)')
  mapply(function(x, y)
    lapply(x, function(dat)
      sapply(dat, function(z)
        str_replace(z, extract_replace, y)) %>% data.frame()), per, pr_r, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

However, this does not produce the results I am after.

Expected output:
when values `brain` are found we should get `log(brain)`, when `body` is found we should get `I(body^2)` in replacement.

Expected output:

```
[[1]]
         X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6       X7       X8       X9
1     log(brain)  nondream     dream     sleep gestation predation exposure   danger     I(body^2)
2  nondream     dream     sleep gestation predation  exposure   danger     I(body^2)    log(brain)
3     dream     sleep gestation predation  exposure    danger     body    log(brain) nondream
4     sleep gestation predation  exposure    danger      I(body^2)    log(brain) nondream    dream
5 gestation predation  exposure    danger      I(body^2)     brain nondream    dream    sleep

[[2]]
         X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6       X7       X8        X9
1     log(brain)  nondream     dream     sleep gestation predation exposure   danger      I(body^2)
2  nondream     dream     sleep gestation predation  exposure   danger     I(body^2)     log(brain)
3     dream     sleep gestation predation  exposure    danger     body    log(brain)  nondream
4     sleep gestation predation  exposure    danger      I(body^2)    brain nondream     dream
5 gestation predation  exposure    danger      I(body^2)     log(brain) nondream    dream     sleep
6 predation  exposure    danger      I(body^2)     brain  nondream    dream    sleep gestation
```

UPDATE:
When trying to use it on a vector, for example the names of the datasets. Say for example, I want `log(X1)` to change to `X1`, this fails when trying the following:

```
pr_replace <- c('log(X1)', 'log(X8)')
extract_replace <- c('X1', 'X8')
lapply(per, names) %>% map(., ~ .x %>% str_replace_all(.x, setNames(extract_replace, pr_replace)))
```

reproducible code (updated):

```
per <- list(structure(list(`log(X1)` = c("brain", "nondream", "dream", 
"sleep", "gestation"), X2 = c("nondream", "dream", "sleep", "gestation", 
"predation"), X3 = c("dream", "sleep", "gestation", "predation", 
"exposure"), X4 = c("sleep", "gestation", "predation", "exposure", 
"danger"), X5 = c("gestation", "predation", "exposure", "danger", 
"body"), X6 = c("predation", "exposure", "danger", "body", "brain"
), X7 = c("exposure", "danger", "body", "brain", "nondream"), 
    `log(X8)` = c("danger", "body", "brain", "nondream", "dream"
    ), X9 = c("body", "brain", "nondream", "dream", "sleep")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(`log(X1)` = c("brain", 
"nondream", "dream", "sleep", "gestation", "predation"), X2 = c("nondream", 
"dream", "sleep", "gestation", "predation", "exposure"), X3 = c("dream", 
"sleep", "gestation", "predation", "exposure", "danger"), X4 = c("sleep", 
"gestation", "predation", "exposure", "danger", "body"), X5 = c("gestation", 
"predation", "exposure", "danger", "body", "brain"), X6 = c("predation", 
"exposure", "danger", "body", "brain", "nondream"), X7 = c("exposure", 
"danger", "body", "brain", "nondream", "dream"), `log(X8)` = c("danger", 
"body", "brain", "nondream", "dream", "sleep"), X9 = c("body", 
"brain", "nondream", "dream", "sleep", "gestation")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Are these coming from a model? Whta type of model? The model does save the variables. You do not need regular expressions here

Comment: Also you have not yet closed your previous question and you have asked another one. Does that mean you are not satisfied with the solution given there by @akrun?

Comment: You don't need to paste and collapse,  just create those as two vectors and then use named vector to replace i.e. `map(per, ~ .x %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_replace_all(.x, setNames(pr_replace, extract_replace)))))`

Comment: Great. Though there is just one upvote(mine). I believe you do not have enough tokens/points to upvote. Thats fine. Now back to this question, Can you tell exactly what you want to replace in your `per` list

Comment: @akrun this seems to produce the same result as my first attempt. Essentially, for `brain` it has to be replaced with `log(brain)`, I think because I used paste and collapse, I instead get `log(brain)|I(body^2)`

Comment: I meant `pr_replace <- c('log(brain)','I(body^2)')` and `extract_replace <- c('brain','body')` i.e. when you use the pasted output in replacement, it literally processes that

Comment: @akrun Ah okay! I see the pattern now because we're using map then we iterate over each of them across all the lists. It is working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `paste`ing the elements in the `replacement` (which literally process it compared to the evaluation in `pattern` for `|`), we can create two `vectors` or a single named vector where the names should match the substring in the original data to replace the values from the vector

```
pr_replace <- c('log(brain)','I(body^2)')
extract_replace <- c('brain','body')
named_vec <- setNames(pr_replace, extract_replace)
```

Now, we loop over the `list` with `map`, loop `across` the columns of the datasets and apply `str_replace` with a named vector

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
per <- map(per, ~ .x %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_replace_all(.x, 
        named_vec))))
```

-output

```
per
[[1]]
          X1        X2        X3        X4        X5         X6         X7         X8         X9
1 log(brain)  nondream     dream     sleep gestation  predation   exposure     danger  I(body^2)
2   nondream     dream     sleep gestation predation   exposure     danger  I(body^2) log(brain)
3      dream     sleep gestation predation  exposure     danger  I(body^2) log(brain)   nondream
4      sleep gestation predation  exposure    danger  I(body^2) log(brain)   nondream      dream
5  gestation predation  exposure    danger I(body^2) log(brain)   nondream      dream      sleep

[[2]]
          X1        X2        X3        X4         X5         X6         X7         X8         X9
1 log(brain)  nondream     dream     sleep  gestation  predation   exposure     danger  I(body^2)
2   nondream     dream     sleep gestation  predation   exposure     danger  I(body^2) log(brain)
3      dream     sleep gestation predation   exposure     danger  I(body^2) log(brain)   nondream
4      sleep gestation predation  exposure     danger  I(body^2) log(brain)   nondream      dream
5  gestation predation  exposure    danger  I(body^2) log(brain)   nondream      dream      sleep
6  predation  exposure    danger I(body^2) log(brain)   nondream      dream      sleep  gestation
```

---

For the updated case with column names, wrap with `fixed` as well as there are metacharacters (`()`) along with partial matching

```
map(per, ~ str_replace_all(names(.x), 
       fixed(setNames(extract_replace, pr_replace))))
[[1]]
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7" "X8" "X9"

[[2]]
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7" "X8" "X9"
```

Comment: A quick question: why is `mutate` used for this instance? presuming we do not have a dataset, but just a string of characters, then by using `mutate` I would get an error like: `no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"`, so what role does mutate take?

Comment: @DollarTune-bill then you don't need mutate.  Your example showed a list of data.frames, thus column in the data.frame is looped within mutate iusing `across`.  If you have only a list of vectors, then you can directly apply the str_replace_all i.e. `map(per, ~ str_replace_all(.x, named_vec))`

Comment: Ah I see, as for an example - I have updated my reproducible code and added an update to see how I can do this over vectors. I have tried what you mentioned as shown in the update of the post, but it won't replace the names of the vector.

Comment: @DollarTune-bill The `per` object is still a list of data.frames i.e. `str(per)#
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  9 variables:`, thus it would work with `mutate` as I showed in the post

Comment: @DollarTune-bill I think what is happening is that your new code(just saw the names), can have some partial matching.  One way is to wrap with `fixed` i.e. `map(per, ~ str_replace_all(names(.x), fixed(setNames(extract_replace, pr_replace))))#
[[1]]
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7" "X8" "X9"

[[2]]
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7" "X8" "X9"`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! so `fixed` would only replace those values when they're exact, whereas because many values involve `X` then by partial matching they will all be affected. This might explain why sometimes all of them got replaced when I tried it.

Comment: @DollarTune-bill To prevent partial matching, we may also have to add word boundary (`\\b`) by `paste`ing.  Please consider to post as a new question if there are issues in matching. thanks